# Changing list items color and size in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a list in Xamarin.Forms that I fill using C#. The code for adding items to the list looks like this:

```
stockitems_list.ItemsSource = new[] {

                "test 1",
                "test 2",
                "test 3"

            };
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text is rather small and red, while I want it bigger and black. I found some other topics where this was discussed, but nothing seemed to work for me. My XAML code is:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            <Label x:Name="lbl_apoc_id" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="28" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
            <ListView x:Name="stockitems_list" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False"></ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I tried to add CellView and set the color of Label, but that resulted in no text at all (as if the list in C# was not put there anymore).

Does someone has the solution for this?

Regards, Ganesh

Comment: Did you check the ListView ItemTemplate docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance)

```
<ListView x:Name="stockitems_list" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontColor="Red" FontSize="Large" />
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```